# In excel, how can I format raw data so that the second number is in parentheses?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a row with the following numbers, 2 in each cell:

```
4 (8) | 3.8 (12) | 5 (7) | 4.6 (35)| 5 (8) | 4.4 (27)
```

I'd rather write them like this:

```
4 8   | 3.8 12   | 5 7   | 4.6 35  | 5 8   | 4.4 27
```

Can I enter them into the cells without the parenthesis and format them at the end to add the parenthesis?

Here's an image for what I mean (its the top row):
https://www.dropbox.com/s/p5byjtlumolwkb3/Screen%20Shot%202014-11-23%20at%208.35.37%20AM.png?dl=0

Thanks !!!

Comment: do you realize that your screenshot does not match your description? there you seem to have 2 distinct numbers in each cell, which is also called **text** data type. did you change your spreadsheet to have double the number of columns so each cell contains only 1 number?

Comment: That's what I described. I have two numbers in each cell.

Comment: no you didn't. but I updated the question for you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, simply select the cells you want formatted, then right-click > Format Cells. Go to the "Number" tab, and on the left click "Custom" then enter `(0.0#);(-0.0#)` as the format.

You could also use conditional formatting if you wanted to do every other column automatically. Select the range you want formatted, the go to the Home ribbon > Conditional Formatting > New Rule. Then select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format." Enter this formula: `=ISEVEN(COLUMN(A1))`, then click "Format...", go to the "Number" tab, click "Custom", and enter `(0.0#);(-0.0#)` as the format.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write this answer to both of you.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write this answer to both of you.
For BobbitWormJoe: I tried both and maybe I messed it up because neither solution did the trick. The first didn't have any effect on the numbers (I can record my screen depicting it). With the second, Ribbon > Conditional Formatting > New Rule gives me a box with nowhere to enter the formula ( https://www.dropbox.com/s/atbihqbknat77er/Screen%20Shot%202014-11-24%20at%208.06.12%20PM.png?dl=0).

Comment: good answer to the original question when assuming each number is in a separate cell. no good for the updated clarified question though.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your number is in cell A2. Type this into cell B2:

```
="(" & A2 &")"
```

That will add parenthesis to your number.

Comment: True, but I think he wanted to have parentheses appear around raw data after entry, not in another cell with a formula.

Comment: For MicroR: BobbitWormJoe is right that I want the parentheses to appear around raw data after entry, in the same cell -- but thank you though. I should've been more clear.

Comment: Oh, well maybe the above might help someone.